# class FragmentResultListener, error cannot find symbol

Tags: android, fragment

I'm facing to a problem which I do not understand. Playing with Fragment and trying to get a result from my second fragment into my firstfragment. I got a compilation error about "FragmentResultListener".

```
error: cannot find symbol
        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   class FragmentResultListener
  location: class FirstFragment
```

I was using the code proposed by [android dev](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between#java).
Here the code:

```
public class FirstFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentResultListener a = new FragmentResultListener() { } ;
        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String key, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {
                // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
                String result = bundle.getString("bundleKey");
                // Do something with the result...
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

   ...
```

I'm using Android 4.0 from May 20, 2020.

Many thanks for your help,

Fred

Answer (score 0):

Fred, I had this issue when I updated androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha08 to 1.0.0-alpha09. I had to go back to the previous version, it seems that the documentation hasn't been updated to inform of the disappearance of that method.